# highcharts | add points per week over the last 3 months

Tags: laravel, api, highcharts

I would like to create several graphics using the highcharts library.
One of my graphs is to display the number of toys sold per week over the last 3 months as of today.
I only have the id of the object and its date. On my X axis I would like to display the last 3 months with one dot per week.
Data arrives from an api.

pointStart = todays's date -3 months

pointsInterval = 1 week

pointEnd = today

```
today = Date.now();

xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: this.today,
      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data:
  }]
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @HCP, Could you provide me with a sample of your data?

Comment: At the moment my data comes back from this format 0: {products_id: 1059733, products_date_added: "2016-01-28T00:00:00+01:00"}
1: {products_id: 6128961, products_date_added: "2016-10-04T00:00:00+02:00"}

Comment: And what values you want to show on the chart? You need to adapt your data to the format required by Highcharts (x, y).

Comment: I would like to display on the X axis one point per week with the number of games sold per week over the last 3 months.

Comment: But your data contains only `products_id` and `products_date_added` information.